# PUSH JSON items to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have this JSON string

```
{"Task": [Hours per Day],"Work": [11],"Eat": [6],"Commute": [4],"Sleep": [3]}
```

I want to push it's items to a jQuery array.

I already tried `JSON.parse`.

Normally I can push parameters like this:

```
MyArr.push(['Task','Hours per Day']);
MyArr.push(['Work','11']);
MyArr.push(['Eat','6']);
```

and so on.

How can I do the same with the JSON string?

Comment: Could you post the actual JSON string you have. What you've shown is a syntactic mess that's hard to make sense of. Also, could you post the expected output of the object

Comment: That's not a valid JSON string. Do you have something that passes [a linter](https://jsonlint.com)?

Comment: what language is this even in? we can't do jack until you give us better question details

Comment: I got this string from converting a dictionary to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just parse the JSON into an object and loop through?

```js
var json = '{"Task": ["Hours per Day"],"Work": [11],"Eat": [6],"Commute": [4],"Sleep": [3]}'
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
MyArr = []
for (var key in obj) {

    MyArr.push([key, obj[key][0]])
}
console.log(MyArr)
```

Comment: Now you've edited the answer, yes it will, but only because you're pushing to arrays in the properties of the object, not the object itself.